# Android: Repositioning ImageView

Tags: android, image, positioning, android-imageview

i have 2 imageview. first one for containing the image and the other one as the frame.
i already set image position to have the same position as the frame after loading the image.
i also already check the value and its the same.
but somehow the image position is not the same as the frame when i try changing picture with 2 different size (width x height).

```
ivProfilePicture.setX(ivFrame.getX());
ivProfilePicture.setY(ivFrame.getY());
```

by the way, i use custom imageview for the image container, i only custom the function onMeasure. there's no image repositioning.

Comment: dont use two ImageViews, use one that shows a compound LayerDrawable (image + frame)

Comment: i'm still stranger to that, can you give any example link?

Comment: http://myandroidtipsandtricks.blogspot.nl/2012/09/drawables-part-ii.html?m=1